# How to flatten or pivot an array to a single object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, underscore.js, array-merge

I have several arrays I would like to flatten to a single object. Can anyone see a good way to map or pivot the data from this:

```
Something: [
  {"Test":0,"Count":206,"Abc":0},
  {"Test":2,"Count":119,"Abc":3},
  {"Test":1,"Count":207,"Abc":3},
  {"Test":3,"Count":129,"Abc":8,
  {"Test":4,"Count":122,"Abc":2}
]
```

to this?

```
{
  Name: "Something",
  Test0: 206,
  Test1: 207,
  Test2: 119,
  Test3: 129,
  Test4: 122
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward loop. There's nothing generic that does it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.flattenOn=function(out,key,value)
{
    for(var i=0,l=this.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        out[key+''+this[i][key]]=this[i][value];
    }
    return out;
};

var obj={
  Something:[
  {"Test":0,"Count":206,"Abc":0},
  {"Test":2,"Count":119,"Abc":3},
  {"Test":1,"Count":207,"Abc":3},
  {"Test":3,"Count":129,"Abc":8},
  {"Test":4,"Count":122,"Abc":2}
  ]
};

var output={};
output.Name='Something';
output=obj.Something.flattenOn(output,'Test','Count');
alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Below is the **Fiddle** for the same.
http://jsfiddle.net/67aXK/

Answer (score 1):

```
var newSomething = {};
newSomething.name = 'Something';
for (var i=0,l=Something.length;i<l;i++) {
  newSomething['Test'+Something[i].Test] = Something[i].Count;
}
```